# Getting `list` object no attribute error in BS4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am new to `bs4` and am trying to experiment by building a price bot for Crypto currencies. This is the code I have so far:

```
import requests
import bs4
import csv
from datetime import datetime

def remove_all_whitespace(x):
    try:
        x = x.replace(" ", "")
    except:
        pass
    return x

def trim_the_ends(x):
    try:
        x = x.strip(' \t\n\r')
    except:
        pass
    return x

def remove_unneeded_chars(x):
    try:
        x = x.replace("$", "").replace("RRP", "")
    except:
        pass
    return x

URL = ("https://coinmarketcap.com/assets/golem-network-tokens/")

response = requests.get(URL)

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text)

price = soup.select("span#quote_price.text-large").get_text()

print (price)
```

But I am getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

What am I doing wrong? From my understanding the `.select` does not work with `list` items, but how am I pulling a `list` ?

Comment: `select` may not take `list` arguments, but it (apparently) can return a `list`, I assume handle  when multiple items satisfy the request criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `soup.select()` **returns** a **list** of matches; the selector can match 0 or more times.

If you wanted to retrieve just *one* match, use the `soup.select_one()` method, which returns the first match, or `None` if there are no matches:

```
price = soup.select_one("span#quote_price.text-large").get_text()
```

However, the page you loaded *doesn't contain that information*. The page instead uses Javascript to load data over AJAX. `requests` is not a browser and won't load external resources or execute Javascript code.

The page loads the prices from https://graphs.coinmarketcap.com/currencies/golem-network-tokens/, load that instead:

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('https://graphs.coinmarketcap.com/currencies/golem-network-tokens/')
>>> data = r.json()
>>> data['price_usd'][-1][1]
0.309104
```

The first element of each entry in that list is a timestamp in microseconds:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(data['price_usd'][-1][0] / 1000)
datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 29, 18, 34, 46)
```

You should probably use their [published API](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/) instead however:

```
https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/golem-network-tokens/
```

Comment: Thank you for this - now I am getting the following error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
`; I am assuming this means that it cannot find anything.

Comment: @sgerbhctim: I did specify in my answer that `select_one()` returns `None` if there are no matches.

Comment: Right, would you by any chance tell me where I am going wrong with the CSS/HTML tags? I feel as though I am doing it correctly.

Comment: @sgerbhctim: the URL you are loading uses AJAX to load further data; `requests` only loads the directly-referenced URL, it's not a browser that'll load referenced assets or execute Javascript code.

Comment: @sgerbhctim: as such, be careful that the DOM you are inspecting in the browser could be the result of Javascript code having been executed that alters the object tree. You need to look at the *original source code for the page* to see what requests is  likely to be served. Look at the network tab in the developer tools to see if there are extra requests that load the actual data you want to extract, etc.

Comment: @sgerbhctim: I added a call to their JSON API; the span you wanted to extract is almost certainly the most recent USD price entry.

Comment: The second way you suggested would most definitely be my ideal option, thank you for that. However, the prices loaded by the code I am using vs. the second way is giving different prices.

Comment: @sgerbhctim: You'll have to take that up with that site.

Comment: @sgerbhctim: I do note that their official API has a *newer timestamp*, so I'd think that that figure is accurate, just fresher.

Comment: Any chance you can show me an example of how you pull from their api? Really appreciate this info.

Comment: `requests.get('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/golem-network-tokens/').json()[0]`